# How can I conditionally redirect, immediately after serving index.html in an AngularJS SPA?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

We have a site that serves up an index.html file using Asp.net MVC when you hit the root, and then uses AngularJS 1.2.4 as a Single Page Application. I need to serve the SPA, but would like to immediately redirect to a route. Basically, a user will be clicking a link in an email, and I need to send them to that route.

Serving the Index.html this way:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CachingUtility.SetNoCache(Response);
        var path = "index.html";
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseDist"]))
        {
            path = "dist/index.html";
        }
        return File(path, "text/html");
    }
```

From here AngularJS $routeProvider takes over:

```
...
 .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
 }])
 ...
 .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/products', {
        templateUrl: '/application/app/product/products.html',
        controller: 'ProductsCtrl'
 });
 ... etc,
```

Is there a different way I can serve up the index.html, or something I can do with the router to achieve this? I'm trying to avoid serving up a whole new SPA for these few routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you are accessing your page from outside your application.

To achieve that I would recommend you using ***ui-router***. In addition I haven´t worked on any robust app which doesn´t use a library that helps you with routing.

**Why does it worth to use it?**

According to the following post in the section [Why You Should Use UI-Router](http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/) you have sometimes multiple sections on your view when for example you have ***footer, header, sidebar***, etc which are variable of content, so this powerful library is very helpful. So by using it you must setup a state provider the following way:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
    url: "/contacts",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})
```

So the only thing you would need is : **myurl/contacts** or whatever you want yo pass from the hyperlink on your mail.

If you want something more powerful ([passing url parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-routing)) something that I´ve done is setting up the route as well as the language which the route should implement when coming from outside. And the implementation would look like that:

```
.state('signup', {
            url: 'myUrl + '/signup?lang',
            params: {
                lang: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
            controller: 'signupCtrl'
        })
```

If you pay attention, I add the parameter I´m passing at the end of the url but by default it is null, but that´s only necessary when you pass a parameter (You would only need something like the first snippet) After that you require to get the parameters from inside your controller and then use them any way you want.

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', 
   { url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
    $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
     },
```

So, in summary, if you decide using ui-router and it answer your question

> Is there a different way I can serve up the index.html, or something I
>   can do with the router to achieve this?

1. Add the ui-router library
2. Set up your route.js file
3. Set up the stateProvider
4. Pass the right url to the hyperlink on your email.

Don´t go to far with my explanation and try it out without the ui-router library if you feel like your app won´t be too robust.

Comment: I was able to use ui-router and get it to work; as well, I was able to keep ngRoute, and that works as well. I did not understand that Asp.net would server the SPA and keep the URL as 'http://example.com/#/routeName', and ngRoute can then pick up the route '#/routeName' correctly. Thank you for the guidance, I apologize for my misunderstanding.